# The phrase "running into to you"

Tags: meaning

Is there any difference when one says *running into to you* and *running into you*?
If yes, what is it?

Comment: Think about it for a moment. Literally speaking, running into someone means collision. It is used informally to say that you met someone unexpectedly. "Running into to you" makes no sense.

Comment: The difference is that the first one has an extra word that renders it meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

*Running into to you* is wrong. *Running into you* means *meeting you by chance*.

Comment: OK- I just had some friend of mine do some research -and the Wren And Martin Book of English Grammar says this:
when it's somebody you run into -you say run into to you.
when it's something (an object) you run into - you say run into you.

Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question, but I intend to do  some more analysis and will let you know. In the meanwhile, I'd appreciate if you can also do some research and let me know? All answers are welcome. 

Best,
Vaishali

Comment: Since I am reluctant to correct a published work on English grammar (even one first written in 1935), I believe your friend has misread the text.